# can't find undefined element

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I keep getting this issue "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of undefined at HTMLInputElement.filterNames" but it is defined.  I've been stumped by this for 40mins now and I can't seem to figure this out. 
      https://jsfiddle.net/0bhepryk/1/

```
// Get input element
var filterInput = document.getElementById("filterInput");
// Add event listener
filterInput.addEventListener("keyup", filterNames);

function filterNames(){
  //Get value of input                                  //This make is upper cased.
  var filterValue = document.getElementById("filterInput").value.toUpperCase();
  //Get Names ul
  var ul = document.getElementById("names");
  //Get lis from ul
  var li = ul.querySelectorAll("li.list-group-item");
  //Loop through list-group-items
  for(var i = 0; i < li.length; i++){
    var a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
    //If matched  //a.innerHTML grabs whats inside the a tag, which is the names.
    if(a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filterValue) > -1){
      li[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      li[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: is it `let a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];` that is throwing the error? Your fiddle is not working at all

Comment: I think it's because your first list item `li` doesn't have any anchor tags so returning as undefined. I also found that by simply adding `console.log(li[i]);` before your `if` statement.

Comment: First thing, all `<ul>` have same id's `names` which is wrong. Also the header `<li>` with class `list-group-item` doesn't have `<a>` tag in them (like A, B and C). You should either give a different class name for header `li` tags or check for `a` tag element under `li` before calling `getElementsByTagName`.

Comment: The error message does not match your code. I do not see any attempt to read a `getElementsByTagName` property from anything. The error I see in your fiddle is *"Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undefined"*

Comment: You can not have more than one element with the same id. Ids are singular.

Answer (score 0):

You should handle if `a` is not undefined. why? because there are `<li>`'s that does not contain a `<a>` and so `.getElementsByTagName()` returns an empty array for not found element and `[0]` is undefined.

```
let a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];

if (a)
{
  //If matched  //a.innerHTML grabs whats inside the a tag, which is the names.
  if(a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filterValue) > -1){
    li[i].style.display = "";
  } else {
    li[i].style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

hope that helps